# Would Optane drive or SSD benefit more when web browsing is slow?

Tags: memory, ssd, performance, browser, optane

I have a specific performance issue, which is that I tend to have many windows with many tabs open (across both FireFox and Chrome).

This leads to frequent stalls/freezes, presumably when either (a) browser cache disk IO happens or (b) when pagefile gets read/written on disk (browser memory needs exceed available RAM due to # of tabs open, especially in Chrome). I'm unsure how to test which one causes the freezing.

In either of these specific scenarios, which would offer me best performance improvement for the browsers?

The two options are

A. Mid-line SSD (such as Samsung EVO). It will NOT be crappy slow one like Toshiba; nor super high end fast one like Samsung Pro.

B. Optane memory drive (16GB or 32GB) with hard drive.

Assume that the PC in question fully support Optane drives (e.g. is Kaby Lake with Win10) so that support not one of the factors to consider. RAM is 8GB to 16GB but either way the amount of tabs would make it certain that pagefile swapping would occur).

Comment: I tried to research on my own but most of the reporting is based on standard disk benchmarks without explaining how that tracks with two specific IO patterns I am concerned about (e.g. http://www.pcworld.com/article/3191706/storage/optane-memory-review-why-you-may-want-intels-futuristic-cache-in-your-pc.html)

Comment: looks like you run into memory pressure, so update the RAM

Answer (score 1):

Optane technology was specifically developed to target users still using hard disk drives instead of solid state drives. See this article for reference:

http://www.pcworld.com/article/3184464/storage/intel-optane-memory-has-a-mission-make-hard-drives-faster-than-ssds.html

A solid state drive will definitely perform better in real world use. The question you have to ask yourself is a value proposition:

- Are you going to cannibalize your current PC by re-using parts, specifically the hard disk drive(s), and will you be using that hard disk drive as the installation drive for your operating system? Alternatively, will you be using a different hard disk drive in the new build as an OS install drive?

If the answer to either question is yes, then Optane might offer you benefit.

- Can you get equivalent storage on an SSD at the same price point?

A solid state drive will perform better, so if you can get the space you need and your cost/GB is within your budget then SSD would be the better option. Remember that the price difference between your skylake and kaby lake builds should factor into your calculations here, since you're basing this decision on HDD/SSD/Optane compatibility.

Without knowing how many hard drives you can fit into your computer (didn't see mention of form factor or drive capacity), I would recommend the solid state drive option regardless of which system you build. The hardware you're buying is powerful enough, and SSD storage is cheap enough, that using a hard disk drive for your operating system is practically kneecapping it for daily use and you don't even save a ton of money.

If budget is a concern, and your PC can fit multiple hard drives, a viable and affordable option would be to buy a smaller SSD (120-250 GB) for your OS and install the hard disk drive you currently have for backup and extra storage.

EDIT: If you're looking for the answer to a question you didn't ask until a tag along comment to an answer, then here you go: from your reported use habits and your specific concerns, the Optane memory would perform faster. You wouldn't notice the real world difference, because having a page file on an SSD would literally solve your problem (for a whole lot less money). At the queue depths you're trying to work with, an SSD wouldn't be held back by the lower performance seen at lower queue depths. You're also boxing yourself into Intel's hardware ecosystem by going this route, but that's not something that bothers everyone. I still recommend an SSD, but technically speaking yes the Optane memory technology will execute more read/write instructions per second to the page file and to the browser cache.

Comment: This answer looks at a big picture but doesn't answer the actual specific question I have asked, sorry. I didn't ask which is more coat effective. I asked which is faster if both are an option, **for very specific performance/usage profile**

Comment: For the record, here's the question you asked:

In either of these specific scenarios, which would offer me best performance improvement for the browsers? 

Here's the answer I gave:

A solid state drive will definitely perform better in real world use. I fail to see how that didn't address your question, because your comment here doesn't reflect the original question you asked, sorry.

Comment: there's a difference between typical 'real world use' (which involves running programs from h/drive, or writing data files); and specific web browser performance usage mostly likely centered around page file. SSDs and Optane perform differently depending on specific usage patterns (and the question wasn't about hard/drive; but specifically H/drive with Optane)

Comment: We are discussing your specific problem, I was referencing your real world uses. I would have specified otherwise. And I'm aware of the differences between SSD's and HDD/Octane, I explained them to you above.

Comment: "A solid state drive will definitely perform better in real world use" - Do you have some data to back that up? The PC World article you link provides a limited comparison of HDD to HDD+Optane, along with some slides from Intel bragging about how great Optane is compared to SSDs. Reviews [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-optane-3d-xpoint-memory,5032-4.html) and [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/11210/the-intel-optane-memory-ssd-review-32gb-of-kaby-lake-caching) suggest that Optane *usually* does outperform Flash-based SSDs.

Comment: @8bittree I had seen the Tom's Hardware review, but not the Anandtech one. My understanding is that the Optane module would function as a.)  a separate memory cache, and not b.) one unified with the system virtual memory. In situation "a" I would still be correct, as the page file would still be on the physical disk and unless I missed something in the Optane docs would do nothing to improve pagefile access speed. In situation "b" I would be incorrect, but both of your links seem to imply that "a" is the case. I stand by my recommendation for an SSD over an Optane/HDD setup.

Answer (score -1):

Consider your RAM, a quick look at Task Manager shows Chrome and Firefox take up A LOT of memory; especially with tab browsing. Faster RAM or in some cases more RAM (if you are capped out) will certainly make a difference here.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-uses-too-much-memory-ram

https://www.techspot.com/article/1193-chrome-performance-memory-tweaks/

Comment: Already capped out fastest biggest ram. This doesn't answer the question at all